# pandas: return average of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How do you output average of multiple columns?

```
Gender   Age     Salary     Yr_exp   cup_coffee_daily
  Male    28    45000.0        6.0                2.0
Female    40    70000.0       15.0               10.0
Female    23    40000.0        1.0                0.0
  Male    35    55000.0       12.0                6.0
```

I have `df.groupby('Gender', as_index=False)['Age', 'Salary', 'Yr_exp'].mean()`, but it still only returned the average of the first column `Age`. How do you return the average of specific columns in different columns? Desired output:

```
Gender   Age     Salary   Yr_exp
  Male  31.5    50000.0      9.0
Female  31.5    55000.0      8.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you type df.applymap(type), I think 'Salary', 'Yr_exp' is string for some reason

Comment: @Wen Oh yes you're right. Weird that some of the values are not numeric. Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Given this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Gender": ["Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"],
    "Age": [28, 40, 23, 35],
    "Salary": [45000, 70000, 40000, 55000],
    "Yr_exp": [6, 15, 1, 12]
})

df
   Age  Gender  Salary  Yr_exp
0   28    Male   45000       6
1   40  Female   70000      15
2   23  Female   40000       1
3   35    Male   55000      12
```

Group by gender and use the [`mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) function:

```
df.groupby("Gender").mean()
         Age   Salary  Yr_exp
Gender                       
Female  31.5  55000.0     8.0
Male    31.5  50000.0     9.0
```

Edit: you may need to change the way you're indexing after `groupby()`: `df['Age', 'Salary']` gives a `KeyError`, but `df[['Age', 'Salary']]` returns the expected:

```
   Age  Salary
0   28   45000
1   40   70000
2   23   40000
3   35   55000
```

Try changing

```
df.groupby("Gender", as_index=True)['Age', 'Salary', 'Yr_exp'].mean()
```

to

```
df.groupby("Gender", as_index=True)[['Age', 'Salary', 'Yr_exp']].mean()
```

Comment: Adding a reset_index so that we get the group as a dataframe is the final step.

Comment: What is the different df.groupby('Gender', as_index=False)['Age', 'Salary', 'Yr_exp'].mean(), I think op's know how to do mean with groupby , and this is not the question .

Comment: Agree with Wen, this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your answer, `df.groupby("Gender", as_index=True)[['Age', 'Salary', 'Yr_exp']].mean()` was exactly what I tried (well I used index=False) and it only returned the first column, which is `Age`. If I used only `.mean()` without specifying which columns, it would give me all the columns but there are other columns that I don't need. Best scenario is that I define my own columns to output if possible. (Sorry, I should have mentioned it in my question, will edit it now)

Comment: @Karma - what versions of Python and Pandas are you using?

Comment: @JonathanDayton Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.22

Comment: @Karma I'm using the same versions.. Weird.  One possibility might be to `drop` the columns you don't want before using `groupby`, i.e. `df.drop(['Unwanted column'], axis=1).groupby('Gender', as_index=True).mean()`?

Comment: @JonathanDayton I figured out the reason. It seems that some of these columns are not numeric, and I got this DataError, `No numeric types to aggregate`. Sorry, you're right.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [`pandas.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
df.groupby("Gender").agg({'Age' : 'mean', 'Salary' : 'mean', 'Yr_exp': 'mean'})
```

Would result to:

```
         Age    Salary  Yr_exp
Gender          
Female  31.5    55000   8
Male    31.5    50000   9
```

Using `.agg()` give you the chance to apply different functions to a grouped object - something like:

```
df.groupby("Gender").agg({'Age' : 'mean', 'Salary' : ['min', 'max'], 'Yr_exp': 'sum'})
```

Outputs:

```
          Age         Salary    Yr_exp
         mean    min      max   sum
Gender              
Female  31.5    40000   70000   16
Male    31.5    45000   55000   18
```